# Wish to charge battery in caravan from car alternator while travelling

Tags: alternator, electronics, modification, caravan-camper

I would like to run the 12 volt capability of my 3-way caravan fridge whilst travelling rather than the gas. If I put a 12 volt battery in the caravan what system do I use to charge this battery from the car alternator while driving and what wire and car-to-caravan plug would be safe considering the caravan battery would about 22ft (7mts) from the alternator?

Any and all advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't shout - edit your question & title to lower case then people may read it.

Comment: you need to know the current requirement of the fridge. ( You only need the average current, as the battery will handle the startup ).    A standard "7-pin" trailer plug has an aux pin for just this purpose..though I don't know the current limit.

Comment: @agentp is correct.  Large trailers with braking systems use the aux voltage to charge a battery used for emergency braking.  This is a trickle-charge however, and trailer wiring is really only designed for the amperage of incandescent bulbs and small accessories.  10amps seems like a good guess for the limit.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way out & ensure there’s no problem is to use a ‘ANDERSON PLUG SYSTEM’ from the tow bar/rear of car and a seperate lead to your battery on/in/mounted on the A frame of the caravan/camper... 
from there, run (a hard wired 2core cable) seperate line to the fridge in question to your wants... easily done ✅  whilst you have the car mobile or travelling along all ya need to do is mount a relay from the main car battery via: the ignition to pull in when after the car starts  it will keep ya  cold, by doing it to enjoy whenever ya pull over as well.. from another who’s done it themselves